# Declaring a constraint, but what's wrong with my code?

Tags: sqlite

I get a SQL syntax error when I try to run the following in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE R (a INT, b INT, c INT, CHECK (ALL (SELECT a + b FROM R)));
```

Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong?

Gratefully / Nina

Comment: What does the check constraint should check?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm wasting your time! I inadvertently left out a bit of code (c>=), but also it seems that I can't reference the table R when that table has not already been created.

Comment: There is no need to reference the table, merely the columns.